Infinite power tower compressing number line to finite interval?
I’ve been exploring an intriguing infinite power tower and noticed something surprising: it appears to compress the entire infinite positive number line into a finite interval.
Specifically, the function seems to resolve to a finite value for any positive $n$.
Here's the function I'm looking at:
$$f(n) = (n^{1/(n+{1/n})})^{(n^{1/(n+{1/n})})^{(n^{1/(n+{1/n})})^{...}}}$$
i.e. the infinite power tower of $n^{1/(n+{1/n})}$
$$= (n^{1/(n+{1/n})})↑↑∞$$
The global min seems to be $e^{-e}$, which is the limit at $n = e^{-e}$
The global max seems to be $e^{1/e}$ which is the limit at $n = e^{1/e}$
And then we have:
$$lim_{n→0} f(n) = 1$$
$$f(1) = 1$$
$$lim_{n→∞} f(n) = 1$$
A further conjecture based on these critical points at $e^{-e}$, $1$, and $e^{1/e}$:
Every output corresponds to one of two inputs from two consistent, non-overlapping ranges.
Like a mirror on the number line, or folding the function over on itself.
For $0 < n < 1$, 
$$e^{-e} < (n^{1/(n+{1/n})})↑↑∞ < 1$$
One input will always fall in the range $0 < n < e^{-e}$
The other input will always fall in the range  $e^{-e} < n < 1$
For $1 < n < ∞$, 
$$1 < (n^{1/(n+{1/n})})]↑↑∞ < e^{1/e}$$
One input will always fall in the range $1 < n < e^{1/e}$
The other input will always fall in the range $e^{1/e} < n < ∞$
My Question:
Does this make sense? Am I overlooking something fundamental? I’m not a mathematician by training, so I’m hoping to get some feedback on whether this idea holds up, and if so, what the implications might be. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

You can compress the real line into a finite interval also with $f(x)=\arctan(x)$. So, there is nothing unusual about this compression. The set of real numbers has the same cardinality as the interval $[0,1]$ although $[0,1]$ is a very small subset of the set of the real numbers , but still it is uncountable.

Hey @Peter! Thanks for the feedback  Do you find the function trivial? I really, really don't, but honestly you are the first to respond at all, in any way, in months  I find its behavior at 0 and ∞ very interesting, as well as the very fact that an infinite tetration function should converge for any positive n
